# Did the "Windows Web Browser Choice Screen" enforced by the EU make a difference?

Tags: computers, europe, software

In response to a EU anti-trust ruling, European Android users [will soon be presented with a browser choice screen](https://www.theverge.com/2019/4/18/18484796/google-android-browser-ballot-screen-europe-screenshots).

Those of us who are old enough will remember that [the same thing happened on Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BrowserChoice.eu) in 2010.

Did it work?

- Apparently, the EU seems to think so, or they wouldn't try the same thing with Google now. And we know that Internet Explorer was replaced by Google Chrome in the following years as the most popular browser.

  > [image: Browser use share 2009-2015]
  >
  > <sub>(Image source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Usage_share_of_web_browsers_(Source_StatCounter).svg)</sub>
- On the other hand, we all know that correlation does not imply causation, and that web browser usage significantly changed outside the EU as well in those years.

**Are there any studies that show how much (if at all) the Windows Browser Choice Screen affected the "second browser war"?**

Comment: You ask the question „Did it work?“. I would suggest changing that, since the intent of the regulation was surely no to promote any other browsers, but simply to make consumers aware of possible alternatives. Had the Internet Explorer been a superior product, it would probably still be the browser of choice.

Comment: It seems you are trying to ask if the "EU Browser Choice Screen" contributed to IE's loss of market share. That's perhaps answerable, and what I assume you mean by "did it work".